# thump when braking

Tags: noise, suzuki, braking

Sometimes when I brake I hear a thump that I can hear, and feel through the brake. I have a Suzuki SX4, automatic transmission. It doesn't matter if I brake quickly or slowly and it is just one "thump" that lasts a second. My mechanic said I need to have timing valve cover replaced, said I have a leak. He hasn't retrned my calls where I wanted to ask about the thumping noise. The mechanic does not know about the thump yet, may not have felt it since it is sometimes. thanks for any answers.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The mechanic needs to know the complaint.  There are many possibilities ranging from loose caliper mounts, loose pads in their brackets, to control arm bushings along with many other things. It may take a little bit of time to find the source.